# How to use result from one Function to another

Tags: javascript

I'm new with JavaScript. I need little help with the code below. How can I take totalBalance, and use it in Withdraw function?

```
function depositAcc(){
    let depAmount = prompt('How much do you want to deposit?');
    console.log('Your deposit is complete!', depAmount);
    anotherTrans = prompt('Do you want to do another transaction? yes or no');
    if (anotherTrans == 'yes'){        
        anotherTransaction();
    }else{
        console.log('Thank you for using our Bank!');
        console.log('Your balance is ', depAmount);
        console.log('Have a nice day', userName);
    }
    return totalBalance;
}

function Withdraw(){
    let transaction = prompt('How much do you want to withdraw?');
    if(totalBalance < transation){
        console.log('Insufficient funds!');
    }else{
        totalBalance = totalBalance - transaction;
        console.log('Thank you for using our Bank');
        console.log('Your current balance is', totalBalance);
    } 
}
```

Comment: Start by fixing the variable names that are misspelled.

Comment: Also, where is `totalBalance` coming from?  And how are you invoking these functions?

Comment: Call `depositAcc()` from `Withdraw()`, or store the return value and pass to `Withdraw()`. Also read https://idownvotedbecau.se/noresearch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable `previousBalance` is not defined.

First of all I assume this variable is out of the 2 functions. If not, its not defined, then first define it.

```
let previousBalance = 1000;
```

Then the variable is more global.

Comment: Did you mean to comment on my post?  instead of posting an independent answer?

Comment: Eventually, I fix the code by declaring a global variable. Indeed there was mispell variables.  I fix that, it's all set now. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

**This is how I would do it.**

First, change the withdraw function to include a passed variable.  And use that passed variable in the totalbalance calculation.  I will call this variable previousBalance.

```
function Withdraw(previousBalance){
    let transaction = prompt('How much do you want to withdraw?');
    if(previousBalance < transation){
        console.log('Insufficient funds!');
    }else{
        totalBalance = previousBalance - transaction;
        console.log('Thank you for using our Bank');
        console.log('Your current balance is', totalBalance);
    }
}
```

Secondly, this is how I would call this modified function.

```
let previousBalance = depositAcc();
Withdraw(previousBalance);
```

Comment: You forgot a `}` after the else block

Comment: Thanks, I will fix that.

Comment: I'm going one post by one. I appreciate your help, it was helpful. I wasnt sure how to call modifed function. Thank you again

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `Bank` Object which define both funtion `withdraw` and `deposit` like below. This is very helpfull and you can do any number of operation as you still typing `yes` when you are asked for another transaction

```js
const Bank = function(initialBalance = 0){
    this.totalBalance = initialBalance;

    this.init();
}

Bank.prototype.deposit = function(argument){
    let depAmount = prompt('How much do you want to deposit?');
    this.totalBalance += parseFloat(depAmount);
};

Bank.prototype.withdraw = function(){
    let transaction = prompt('How much do you want to withdraw');
    if(this.totalBalance < transaction) {
        console.log('Insufficient funds!');
    } else {
        this.totalBalance = this.totalBalance - parseFloat(transaction);
    }
};

Bank.prototype.init = function(){
    if(!this.username) {
        this.username = prompt('Let started with your Name');
    }
    let transactionType = parseInt(prompt('Which transaction do you want to perform \n 1 for deposit \n 2 for withdraw'));
    switch(transactionType) {
        case 1:
            this.deposit();
      console.log('Your current balance is', this.totalBalance);
            break;
        case 2:
            this.withdraw();
      console.log('Your current balance is', this.totalBalance);
      break;
    }

    let anotherTransaction = prompt('Do you want to do another transaction? yes or no');
    if(anotherTransaction === "yes") {
        this.init();
    } else {
        console.log('Thank you for using our Bank');
        console.log('Your current balance is', this.totalBalance);
        console.log('Have a nice day', userName);
    }

};

new Bank();
```

You can learn more about how to create [Object Prototype](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/Object_prototypes)

You can define `initialBalance` when you create a instance of Bank object by passing as argument the initial balance like `new Bank(4000)`

Comment: This ties the two functions together and prevents them from being called independently, and also doesn't allow Withdraw() to get the value from another source.   A passed variable is a better solution.

Comment: I made a few changes to use javascript prototype to define a `Bank` object which define `withdraw` and `deposit` function

Answer (score -1):

Where do you assign the totalBalance?
You can call depositAcc function inside Withdraw and put the result in a variable for your use.

Other option is to assign totalBalance outside the two functions and just set is when you want. this is called a global variable

Comment: This should a comment, not an answer

Comment: I cant comment because of my reputation... I will be glade if you can vote me up again (:
@Samathingamajig

Answer (score -1):

You don't assign the variable of `totalBalance` correctly

```js
function Withdraw(){
    let transaction = prompt('How much do you want to withdraw?');
    let totalBalance = depositAcc() // you need to add this line
    if(totalBalance < transation){
        console.log('Insufficient funds!');
    }else{
        totalBalance = totalBalance - transaction;
        console.log('Thank you for using our Bank');
        console.log('Your current balance is', totalBalance);
    } 
}
```

Comment: This requires calling the deposit function every time the withdraw function is called.  It doesn't allow for them to be called independently.  A passed variable is a much better solution.

Comment: It depends on the situation @Velocibadgery